# Temporary table trouble in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I have 2 store procedure :

The first one to create #TempTable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTempTable
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TempTable;
    END 

    CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
        Value real NOT NULL         
END
```

The second one to insert data in my #TempTable

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE InsertData
         @Value real 
    AS
    BEGIN
      INSERT #TempTable (Value) VALUES @Value
    END
```

When I call these procedure I have an error :

```
exec CreateTempTable
exec InsertData" 1
go
```

**Name '#TempTable' not valid in InsertData**

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temp table created inside a sproc is automatically dropped after the sproc ends.

You have a few choices:

- Create the temp table outside of the sproc as a standalone query.  Then it will be dropped after the connection closes
- Create a sproc that first creates the temp table and then calls the other sprocs
- Use a global temp table (careful - concurrency issues can crop up with this)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem here is that you are creating a *local* temporary table, that cannot be accessed outside `CreateTempTable`. You should create a *global* temporary table, by using `##` instead of `#`.

**Edit** Yep, that's it. Here is your fixed script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTempTable
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempTable') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE ##TempTable;
    END 

    CREATE TABLE ##TempTable(
        Value real NOT NULL
    )
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertData
    @Value real 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT ##TempTable (Value) VALUES (@Value)
END
GO

exec CreateTempTable
exec InsertData 1
go
```

Comment: Global temp tables have contention issues if the sproc is ran by more than one user at a time.  It's probably not a good idea to just make it global and call it a day.

Comment: Yes, but that was *not* what the OP asked for. Anyway, thanks for the info.